# Is way to compare two files and save the result as a sed script?

Tags: bash, sed, diff

I have a base file base.txt and two files A.txt and B.txt that inherit form it. I want all txt that replaced in A.txt from base.txt apply on B.txt.

Comment: there is a standard utility for this already on linux ( patch ). see **[patch-command-examples](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/12/patch-command-examples/)**

Comment: From your tags, I take you want to achieve this on the command line, not by writing a program. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you please add an example how the resulting `sed` script should look like given two inputs? It would help if you explain why your want to use `sed` and not other tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
diff -u base.txt A.txt | patch B.txt
```

With `diff` you get what are the differences between `base.txt` and `A.txt`.

Then, with `patch` you apply to file `B.txt` that differences.

Comment: This should rather be a comment. Maybe herzl, wasn't asking without a reason to save the difference as `sed` script.

Comment: Ups, didn't notice the `sed` part.

Answer (score 0):

You can make sed branch and print on a successful replace of A.txt from the text in base.txt and redirect the output to a change file. Then loop over the change file applying the changes to B.txt.

E.g.

`IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in $(< base.txt); do sed -in "s/${a}/something/;t a;b b;:a p;:b" A.txt >> change.txt; done`

`IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b") && for a in $(< change.txt); do sed -in "s/${a}/something/" B.txt; done`

In the first loop, the sed branches on a match to label `:a` with the print command `p`, if there is no match the logic hits the branch and hops over label `:a` and exits without printing.